# Groovy mock method with parameters

Tags: testing, groovy, mocking

I tried to mock some maven classes.

I know I can mock an Interface or a class with maps

```
def projectMock = [ getBasedir: { new File("") } ] as MavenProject
```

But how do I mock a method that receives parameters?

I have tried to use "MockFor" for this:

```
def artifactFactoryMockContext = new MockFor(ArtifactFactory)
artifactFactoryMockContext.demand.createArtifact(1) {groupId, artifactId, version, classifier, type -> artifact }
def artifactFactory = artifactFactoryMockContext.proxyInstance()
```

But I get an UnsupportedOperationException. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Long as you're ok using Groovy Map coercion for mocking instead of a framework, this kind of thing will work for you:

```
def fooMock = [ bar: { baz, thing -> 42 } ] as Foo
```

Now `fooMock.bar("arg1", "arg2")` will return 42.